# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath only fired sometimes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I know this is going to be one of those head-smacker moments.

I have a UITableView from which I need to delete cells.  Problem is, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is only called if I first tap the row and then swipe to show the delete button.  If I swipe the row without explicitly tapping the row, then I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.  I put an NSLog into didSelectRowAtIndexPath and can see the indexPath array when I tap the cell, but nothing if I just swipe without clicking.

I've done my share of searching and I'm 99% sure my delegate is hooked up correctly (usually problem #1) and didn't type didDeselectRowAtIndexPath (usually problem #2).  I also have  in my .h file (problem #3).

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

I should have said: If I swipe the row without explicitly tapping the row, then I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I tap the Delete button.  If I tap the cell and then swipe, I can tap Delete and it deletes as expected.

---

EDIT:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [bandList sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];    

    NSDictionary *dict = [bandList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSLog(@"IndexPath: %@", [indexPath description]);
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        NSDictionary *selectedBand = [bandList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *selectedBandId = [selectedBand objectForKey:@"id"];
        [self deleteMyBand:selectedBandId];
        bandList = [self getSavedBands];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath, the deletion delegate methods and cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: You are sorting your `bandList` each time tableView asks for a new cell. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not the best place to prepare your data. Also, if `bandList` changes over time, your tableView will become inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

These lines jump out at me:

> ```
> NSDictionary *selectedBand = [bandList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
> NSString *selectedBandId = [selectedBand objectForKey:@"id"];
> ```

I don't understand your reasoning for taking a value from an array, sticking it into a dictionary, then getting a string out of that dictionary. Shouldn't the value returned from

`[bandList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Be the same as what you get in `selectedBandId?`

Also, I can't analyze it any further when I don't know what "deleteMyBand" and "getSavedBands" do. Try commenting out those calls and seeing if the visible row itself can be deleted. That may tell you where the problem is.

Comment: bandList is an array of dictionaries.  I have to get the dictionary so I can get the bandId out of it.  All 'delete' and 'get' do is delete/read an array of dictionaries from a plist. I appreciate your input, but I'm really just trying to figure out why a tap cell/swipe cell/tap Delete works but a swipe cell/tap Delete doesn't fire didSelectRowAtPath.  This seems to be more of a UITableView delegate issue to me, although I can't figure out the issue myself, so what do I know.

Comment: I'm guessing that it has something to do with calling the currently selected table row in 'deleteMyBand' or 'getSavedBands'. Not sure why those two NSDictionary and NSString lines bothered me; it seems obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why, but the fact that I was using a sorted NSMutableArray for my source data seems to have been the problem.  When I was deleting the row from the table and updating the MutableArray, I got the crash.  However, if I created my source data as an NSArray, made a mutableCopy of the array into a temporary MutableArray, removed the row, resorted the array, and then wrote the MutableArray back out to an NSArray, everything is peachy.

I don't think this explanation makes sense, but it's the pattern I'm seeing.  If anybody can think of why this might be working, please enlighten me.  My gut tels me it was the sort, but my gut hasn't been correct much lately.